Feed cells in a table taking correct data from another table if cells in other raws match
Say, Excel_Table_1 should compare its ID1 cells with ID2 cells from Excel_Table_2 and if there are any matches take corresponding data from Excel_Table_2's NAME2 and put it into its NAME1
I'm using Excel 2016
So far I've tried:

=IF([@ID1]=Excel_Table_2[@ID2];Excel_Table_2[@NAME2];"empty")

and


=VLOOKUP(E3;H3:I5;2;TRUE)

VLOOKUP seems to be the one I need but I can't force it to show correct result and it looks like its output depends on sorting
I need my Excel_Table_1 look exactly like below:

Can you please help?
Thank you!

You can combine the VLOOKUP and IFERROR functions as shown below to get the desired result(s):
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@ID1],Table2,2,FALSE),"n/a")

Based on your formula:
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E3;H3:I5;2;FALSE),"n/a")

The last argument FALSE of the VLOOKUP function is for exact match.


After replacing all ,s with ;s (the correct sign depends on one's settings, right?) it perfectly works, THANK YOU!
To avoid further questions: was my mistake to link to specific columns instead of the whole table?
And thank you for the tip with IFERROR! )

@YKKY The mistake was using TRUE which is for approximate search. If the question has been answered, please mark  it as solved.
